# How does an OS / Why does an OS render text like this?

Tags: text, ascii, extended-ascii

How does / Why does this happen to text?

---

T̡͕̭ͮͥ̂ͥ̿́̂h̻͔̱̙͍͕̍ͫͫ͂͛͑͗ͦ́a̹̗̟̞͔̥̥̋̽̍̾͗̆ͥͪt̂͟͠͏̖̟̘̗̳̤̗̮'̵̧̧̩͋ͦͤ̽̿ͣ͂s͖̭͉̗̜̯̖ͪͯ̍̅̕ ̛̐ͭ̆͡҉̭̞̪̗̭̖̺͈m̴̫̙͓̙͖̓̈͢y̸̗͎͚̲̩̜ͬ̾ͅ ̴ͪ̃̈ͪ̇ͬ͏̡̭͚̤̣̩͈͚̪̲s̡̔͂̀҉̣̺̭̹͚̜͖oͯ̑̈́͛҉̡͏͓̜̝̱n̹̙̦̓͌̎̿͝'͖̭̝̩͇̆́̌̆͌́̚ͅs̵̮̹ͥ̍͡ ̧̳̰ͥ̂̓w̴̢͙̽ͧ̍͆r̳̳͖͎͎͂̂͑̀ͯ̐̽̕i̗͕̎ͥ̐͡t͓͍̬̹̅̅ͦ̏̃į̛̭̱̣͚̱͇̫͗ń͍̖̲̃͘g̵̣̩͖̥̲͕̽ͦ,̰̱̹̘̣͔̮͕̼ͩ̈́̉͌́̀͞ ̠̭͕͚̞̗̤̗̀̂͒̀͊̓̾̈́̀́ͅb̶̸̻͖͓̻̜ͨ͋͒ͯ̎͐ͪu̵̫̜̺̥̎̊ͅẗ̸̻̩̰͉̭̲̝̗̿ͫ̋͛̄ͯ̏̀͢ ̨̳̲͇͈͚͎͉̠̄̎̓̀ͤ̈́ͣ̾͘y̜ͮo͔̮͛̓͊͂́̌̌͋ͮư̤͚͎̻̝̘̦ͮ͂ͨ͢ ̡̠͍̥͔̭͚͍̗̒̅̂́͘ͅk̋̒ͧ̈́̂̈͌ͣ҉̤͕̪̹̟̯̰̗n̶̻̺͖̲̰̪̤̓̉̅̅͊̐ͥ̿̐͢o̴̸͖̰͉͎̝͆̀ͩw̴̴͎̜͕̠͔ͫ̽̐̾̄ ̰̺̘̤͎͔ͫ̽ͣ̾͠͝ẃ̨̹͚̩̻̱̥̇̇̈́͗͒͊͗ḥ̛̬̱͕̱̣͔͈̅̅ͬ͘a͋҉͝҉͈̗̝t̟̦̭̮͆̈́ͪͩ̈́ͪ̍́ ̡̜͔̩̻͎͍̞͚̠͆͋̓ͮ̍ͭt͚͔̖̜͕ͨ͆̃̿͡h̰̫͉̞͕̠̐͘ȩ̣͔͎ͦͨ͟͠y̢̱̘̞̗̩̠ͨ̋ͯ̿̚͞ ̢̩̰̟̬͖͉͛́͢ͅş͇̺̣̪͕͎̏͂̂̓̏ͧ̅́a̸̢͓͉̤̼͙͐̑̃͂ͩ̔͌͆͗y̜̲͕ͪ̽̈́̓ͯ̈́ͅ;̰͕̩ͫ̓̓̊͞ ̭̟̗ͨͫ͒ͬ͐̎̔̍͌́̕ͅ'̫͔͍͍̳̼͉͉̄̔t͐͗̑͊̎ͤ҉̡͈̼̰͍̻h̡̳̗͍͚̦̗̘̫ͬ̓ͩ͋̃͂ͅę̠̻̗̖̘̲̦͈̥ͧͫ͠ ̵̘͕̼̺̖̙ͧ͂̑͗̾͗̓̾a̠̳͎̖̓͞p̶̡͔͚̺̖̙̓̓̃͋͑̎̂͗p̧̯͉̠͔͌͞l̛͚̣̪͓͕͔̺̠̑͆͛͌͆e̷̡͈͓̞ͮ̄ͩ͊ͦ͑̚͟ ̢̛̜̪̬̓̈͂ͦͮ͆̾d̵̖̻͙̓ò̫͇͍͌̽ḙ̸̯̬̣͆ͯ̍s̷̺̠̟̙̫̫̦̥̈̈́̈́̉ͥ̑̌̕n͐̒ͭ҉̢̹͚̬͉̫̱̟'̲̗̪̩̺͍̲̩̝ͮ̑ͫ͐t̸̯͛͗ͧ̇̐́̀̚ ͉̻ͩ̎̓͋ͦ͑̅͟͠f̗̞̬̺̦͍͙ͫ͛̀͜a̸̡̻̮̝͉ͥ̔̇̓l͖̦̬̻͉̻̑́͂ͯ̿̚̚l̋̆҉̺͇ ̸̥̠̬̰͒͊͝f̹̺̺ͣ̒̓a͈͖̫̰̪̽ͨͬ͑ͯͥ͗͒ŕ̡͇͙̺̺̦ͣͭ̀͂̈̈́̍̏ ͚̥̖̻̮̐͋̽͒͢f̔̈́ͯ̿͌̈́͏̦͎͕̼̼͚̠ͅr̷̨̭͊ͩ̊ͭ͆̈̾͞o̶̰͎͈̥ͧͨ̎̏̎ͪ̇̓̕m̂͑͛̓̍̾ͬ͏͖̠̖̦͇̝ ͑̋͛ͭͮ̄̇͒҉͍̖̮̯̮̼t̷̹͇͖ͤ͆̊ͨ̐ͦh̖̟͖ͭͧ͛̃̉͝e͎͈̹͒̎͊͡ ̸̶̙̻̘̠̮̻̺̃̽̍̃̀t̢̙̒̌̒ṟ̨̹̮̟̙̜ͥ̌ͮ̆̊͛͘͘ĕ̗̠̜̯̰̘̫ͬ̆̌͌͛͡e̞̳̊͂̓ͧ̊̒͟'̧̩̌ͭ̔́͛͝.̰͉͈͇̿ͦͨ͗ͫͣ͑̎ ̷̢̘̻͕̤̎̓̋̓ ̝̺̜̠̪̑̎̐̈͆͢͜͠M̢ͬ̊̀̐͂̈́ͣͧ҉̣̦̟̟͓y̡̤̞͎̹̥̘̞̰̎͐ͯ̃ͤ͐ͫ̇ ̷̦͇̥̜͍̞̌̓͂̒͂̒̆h̩̩̑͐̾́ͨ̐̾̂a̭͔̫̎ͩ̽͛ͮ̽̇ͯn̵̙͖͈̣͈̿̓̂ͯ̊͆̑͆̌́d̵̥͕̟͇̞͕̳̒ͨͅͅw̶̸͕̯̬͇͙̓̔̔͛̏͋r̴̰̻͊́̀̏͛̆͡i͂̀̏͌ͤ͜͏͈͚͚̮̩̗t͋̀͏̯̗͓̼̭̪̹͙i͓͉̤̯͙̮̮̬ͥ̇ͅn̮̻̥͍̐g̛͙̮̗̪̏͗ͮ̚͟ ̢̱̞̩̭̞̖͒ͬ̐́͆͊̀͡i̼͚̺̫͍̟͍͖ͭ̄̈͋͊ͯ̚s̰̞̫̣͈͐̐ͨͯ̊̇̒ ̴̷̡̩͖͔̙̾̈́̾ͬs̗̖̮̰̟ͩ͆̍ĥ̸̤̻̏͂͒ͦͅǐ̵̵͓̺̑͋ͭ̄ͤ̌͞ṭ̪̱̫̦̜ͩ̑ȩ͕̪̫̖̬͔̯̦͐̈͆͗ͧ̄̕͡,͉̫̙͉̼̔͗̈͡ ̢̻͉̟̖̋͌̌͆̽ͧ̊b̛̭̤̤̞̟̈́͆̀̇͢u̷̮̫̗̫ͫ̑̉̃̆͌ͬͨ̇tͨͩ̾̓҉̜͔ ̵̧͇͍̪̹̪͙̍ͫ̈̈́̈̀̚m̸͈̺̞̤̀̆͠y̫̤ͤͣͯ̓̅̉ ̥̲̲̘̩̊ͩͭ̇̋t̷̷̃̂̔̒̔ͪ҉̥̬̳͉̩͓̝y̞̙̓ͨ̑̉p̻̭͙̖̞̘͊̆̈́͠i̛̼̝̪͖̲̹̥̞ͧ̅̍ͥ͠ṉ̷̡̻͍͎͒̆̑͊́ͅg̢̻͇̮͑̂̀̕ ̱͉̘͎͓̫̤̒ͮ̇̆͛̄̋͊͠ḯ͕̪̘̥͖̓ͧ̚s̸͋͜҉͎̖̰̼ ̛̝̳͎͉̲͎̝ͣ͐̄́̒̓̚͢n̶̨͋͋͆҉͎̠̝̱͇̟͚̯ẽ̶̎̆҉̘̰͍̝̙̟a̷̖̳ͫͩͥ̎t̨ͥͧ͂̆ͭ͜҉͕̫̭̱̬ͅ.̴̞͙̾̓ͩͦͫ̚͞ ̻̻̰̰̗̤̍ͫͩ́

Comment: Unicode combinators. For future reference, it's also popularly called "Zalgo text", in reference to [Zalgo](http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/Zalgo)

Comment: Note that this is in fact a perfectly fine text sequence, legibility concerns aside.